# just querying for data points without specifying any aggregators in openTSDB

Tags: opentsdb

I am fairly new to OpenTSDB and time series DB. I have quickly brushed through it's documentation but still I am not clear with certain things. I basically am not interested as much in aggregator functions like sum etc. I have to store metrics like replication lag , number of slow queries , status of the SQL machine against every host which I store in tags like this  ::

```
[
{
"metric":"replicationLag"
"timestamp":new Date.getTime()
"value" : 2.0
"tags": {
 "host":acb-em1.db01.nm.xyz.com
}
}
"metric":"slowQuery"
"timestamp":new Date.getTime()
"value" : 4
"tags": {
 "host":acb-em1.db01.nm.xyz.com
}
]
```

The kind of queries I need to make on this are atmost things like : what were the values of replication lag in a particular given time range. 
1. Is the above mentioned schema good enough for this or is there something better I can do?

For this am using this

the request JSON is

```
{
"start":1410272307100,
"end":1410340000000,
"queries":[
    {
    "metric":"slowQuery",
    "aggregator":"sum",
    "tags":{
    "host":"tg-em-db01.nm.flipkart.com"
    }
    }
    ]
}

Response content : 




   [
    {
    "metric":"slowQuery",
    "tags":{
    "host":"tg-em-db01.nm.flipkart.com"
    },
    "aggregateTags":[],
    "dps":{"1410327176":0,"1410328026":0,"1410328265":0,"1410328401":0,"1410328488":0}
    }
    ]
```

I am not sure that what exactly the "sum" in the aggregators would do as it is giving back an empty content. I don't need a sum anyway but in the docs it is mentioned that it is a "required" field. However I get all the datapoints and their values with this. Still unsure of aggregatorTags and why it is required and how to omit that and just get the datapoints corresponding to that host during a specified time.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregator is, in fact, required in your query, but this doesn't mean it will always be used. In your case, as you noticed, it's just ignored and you receive the data points as you provided them in first place.

The aggregator would have a real role if, for example, your query didn't specified the host tag and a value for it. In this situation, OpenTSDB would sum the values for both hosts before returning them for you, and to make it clear, the field "aggregateTags" would be filled with the hosts it used in the sum.

Comment: Another thing I have found is that there is a none aggregator that will return the raw data.  For full list use this localhost:4242/api/aggregators